# What is the logic in cutting only 50% of the aid to the Palestinians by the US

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, foreign-policy, palestine, foreign-aid

Why does the United States not hold back 100% of the aid it provides to Palestine? Does the aid money benefit some American companies?

Also, by holding back 50%, the damage to the relationship has already been done. In addition, some other countries have picked up a majority of the slack. So the Palestinians are not affected that much and don't have a strong incentive to sit at the table for peace talks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Official reason:

  > The State Department said it was releasing the rest of the installment — $60 million — to prevent the agency from running out of cash by the end of the month and closing down. (*[source](https://www.theaustralian.com.au/news/world/us-withholds-65-million-from-palestinian-aid-programs/news-story/88d1cc6ab7b101d0c49655b32a7de60b)*)
- Other reasons:

  - If you cut 100%, you can't threaten to cut the remaining 50% (which is a viable option if you only cut 50%).
  - Some in USA believe that cutting all aid would be destabilizing:

    > Haley wanted a complete cutoff in U.S. money until the Palestinians resumed peace talks with Israel that have been frozen for years. **But Tillerson, Mattis and others argued that ending all assistance would exacerbate instability in the Mideast, notably in Jordan, a host to hundreds of thousands of Palestinian refugees and a crucial U.S. strategic partner**.
- Additionally, your assertion that "some other countries have picked up a majority of the slack" and "the Palestinians are not affected that much" is 100% false.

  USA cut its aid by $65M just for the first installment (and if they won't pay anymore this year, will have cut by $300M compared to last year).

  The largest contributor to increase funding so far seems to be [Germany with $52.9M](http://www.dw.com/en/eu-pledges-425-million-in-aid-to-palestinians/a-42384920?maca=en-rss-en-all-1573-rdf) and Belgium, with [a whopping $23M over 3 years](http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/01/belgium-pledges-23m-unrwa-aid-cut-180118081044623.html) (less than $8M/year). Seems rather far from "majority" of the slack.

Comment: What kind of strategic role does Jordan play for the US? And what agency would close down if the $60 million were not released (sorry, your link didn't work; it asks me to sign in)?

Comment: @nk379 - these 2 seem like completely separate questions - probably worth just asking as questions on the site.

Comment: @nk379 I believe "the agency" refers to United Nations Relief and Works Agency (UNRWA).

Comment: Also the WH has made comments to the effect of 'were happy to bring back the 50% if you work with us'

Comment: @nk379 regarding Jordan: since the US relationship with Turkey has become somewhat difficult (Israel, support for opposing factions in Syria, Gülen, Turkey + Russia), the US has pivoted to Jordan for some regional military operations.